# Change output directory where test results file is generated

Tags: msbuild, mstest

I am using MSTest to execute my unit tests against a web service on a remote server.

Is there way to change the path to where the results file(.trx) is generated. Currently my test results is generated in the directory which the Exec command is invoked from:

```
 <Target Name="ExecuteTheTests" AfterTargets="StartService" Condition="'$(ServiceStarted)' == 0 And '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
<Message Text="Executing the Unit Tests" Importance="high" />
<PropertyGroup>
  <TestSuccessOrNot>0</TestSuccessOrNot>
</PropertyGroup>
<Exec Command="&quot;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\\Common7\\IDE\\MSTest.exe&quot; /testcontainer:..\..\..\..\\_MyOutput\\UnitTests.dll /detail:testname ">
  <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="TestSuccessOrNot" />
</Exec>
<Error Condition="$(TestSuccessOrNot) == 1" Text="Unit tests fail!" />
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many Bothans died* to bring you this message:

```
mstest.exe /resultsfile:c:\BadPlaceForTestResults.trx
```

- j/k, many Bothans didn't die, they just typed "MsTest.exe /?"